# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "Ljava/lang/String;" field JNI

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Good day. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Implemented getting keys from android / provider / Settings $ System. Keys like ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION look no problem (those described https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System) but such as sms_delivered_sound, he refuses to search. Writes an error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.woodman.testlibsettingsv2, PID: 31133
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "Ljava/lang/String;" field "sms_delivered_sound" in class "Landroid/provider/Settings$System;" or its superclasses
        at com.example.woodman.testlibsettingsv2.frmMain.GetSystemKyesString(Native Method)
        at com.example.woodman.testlibsettingsv2.frmMain.onCreate(frmMain.java:32)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7210)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7201)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6806)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

code

```
    extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_woodman_testlibsettingsv2_frmMain_GetSystemKyesString(JNIEnv *env,
                                                                       jobject instance,
                                                                       jstring key_Name_) {
    const char *key_Name = env->GetStringUTFChars(key_Name_, 0);

    // TODO
    jclass activityThread = env->FindClass("android/app/ActivityThread");
    jmethodID currentActivityThread = env->GetStaticMethodID(activityThread,
                                                             "currentActivityThread",
                                                             "()Landroid/app/ActivityThread;");
    jobject at = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(activityThread, currentActivityThread);

    jmethodID getApplication = env->GetMethodID(activityThread, "getApplication",
                                                "()Landroid/app/Application;");
    jobject context = env->CallObjectMethod(at, getApplication);


    jclass c_settings_system = env->FindClass("android/provider/Settings$System");
    jclass c_context = env->FindClass("android/content/Context");
    if (c_settings_system == NULL || c_context == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    jmethodID m_get_content_resolver = env->GetMethodID(c_context, "getContentResolver",
                                                        "()Landroid/content/ContentResolver;");
    if (m_get_content_resolver == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    jfieldID f_android_string_key = env->GetStaticFieldID(c_settings_system,
                                                          key_Name,
                                                          "Ljava/lang/String;");

    if (f_android_string_key == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    jstring s_android_string_key = (jstring) env->GetStaticObjectField(c_settings_system,
                                                                       f_android_string_key);


    jobject o_content_resolver;
    o_content_resolver = env->CallObjectMethod(context,
                                               m_get_content_resolver);
    if (o_content_resolver == NULL || s_android_string_key == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    jmethodID m_get_string = env->GetStaticMethodID(c_settings_system, "getString",
                                                    "(Landroid/content/ContentResolver;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;");

    if (m_get_string == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    jstring string_key = (jstring) env->CallStaticObjectMethod(c_settings_system,
                                                                       m_get_string,
                                                                       o_content_resolver,
                                                                       s_android_string_key);
    return string_key;
}
```

thank

Comment: The documentation you linked shows no evidence of such a field existing. Is it possible you wanted to call the `getString(ContentResolver, String)` method of settings.System instead?

Comment: below answered.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: I just noticed that you already implement this in the last block of your code. Split up this code in the case where you can get a static field or have to use getString. Alternatively, clear exceptions if the GetStaticFieldID fails and continue with the function.

Comment: Everything. Understood. Thanks to all. The problem was in the crooked code.

Answer (score 1):

This value is not part of system settings. Actually, it can be found on [miui framework](https://github.com/ChameleonOS/miui_framework/blob/master/java/miui/provider/ExtraSettings.java) but not in other Android systems.

There is no public API to read this setting, neither in C++ not in Java. But we know that this value is written in [**system/build.prop**](https://github.com/d8ahazard/MIUI_SHOOTER_DH_GB/blob/master/system/build.prop) file in simple key=value format.

This file is readable for everybody. You don't need JNI to read it, usual C++ or even C file APIs will work perfectly.

A more flexible approach would be to run the `settings` command from your code.

Comment: I do not see the connection between the repositories in the android and the shell. in the terminal, run the settings list system command and see a bunch of keys and their values. here I also need to receive them.

Comment: Fair enough, you can call `system("settings get system sms_delivered_sound")` and parse the output, just as you can run `Runtime.getRuntime.exec("settings get system sms_delivered_sound")` from Java.

Comment: thanks for the advice. but I don’t know where to look. Already reread everything. No where is nothing documented.

Comment: execution of the settings list system command. It shows the number of keys. if you run the settings get system sms_delivered_sound command, it returns file: ///system/media/audio/notifications/MessageSent.ogg. but if I try to get the value of this key through getString, I get an error

Comment: *"if I try to get the value of this key through getString, I get an error"* I cannot verify this, because on my device this setting does not exist, and I don't see your latest code. But I believe that running `settings get` command is easier than fighting the `Settings$System` service with JNI.

Comment: how do i run it from jni? I am writing a library in c ++

Comment: In C++ you can call [system](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system), and you don't need JNI for that.